# Incorrect way of deleting nodes from BST in c?

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree, performance

I am still getting used to C coding, and I was wondering if I am doing my BST node deletion/freeing memory correctly.  Something about using all the handles (what I was told to call pointers to pointers) and pointers makes me suspicious of doing things incorrectly, such as when I free a pointer, then set it to NULL (That, I am almost sure is wrong).

Anyone with C expierience, I would love criticism/feedback on these methods.

```
void killTree(node **node)
{
    if(!(*node)){}
    else
    {
        killTree(&((*node)->left));
        killTree(&((*node)->right));
        printf("DEBUG: Deleting pointer to node of value %d from mem\n", (*node)->key);
        free(*node);
        (*node) = NULL;
    }
}

node** searchTree(node **root, int value)
{
    if(*root)
    {
    if ((*root)->key == value) return root;
    else if((*root)->key > value) searchTree(&((*root)->left), value);
    else searchTree(&((*root)->right), value);
    }
    else return NULL;
}

void removeNode(node **root, int value)
{
node **n = searchTree(root, value);
if((*n) == NULL)
{
    return;
}
if((*n)->left == NULL && (*n)->right ==NULL)
{
    free(*n);
    (*n) = NULL;
}
else if((*n)->right == NULL)
{
    (*n) = (*n)->left;
}
else if((*n)->left == NULL)
{
    (*n) = (*n)->right;
}
}
```

Comment: `else if((*n)->right == NULL)` and `else if((*n)->left == NULL)` clauses: Seems like the original (*n) needs to be free'd?

Comment: `else if((*root)->key > value) searchTree(&((*root)->left), value);` You are ignoring the return value here. Also, you don't *need* recursion, given the double pointer.